# 3D reconstruction with a single rotatable camera

Tags: computer-vision, 3d-reconstruction, slam

I have a rotatable camera mounted in a fixed position. The camera can be rotated with API. I want to do 3D reconstruction about the environment around the camera.

Is it possible to do 3D reconstruction in my setup ? I have read some theories about 3D reconstruction with two cameras. What are the major differences between my setup and a two-camera setup ?

Any tutorials/blogs/samples are welcome ;)

Answer (score 0):

Triangulating points isn't possible during pure rotational motion. Geometrically you can think about how the direction vectors to a feature match from the two camera poses will be parallel and will never meet or will meet at an arbitrary point so the results from triangulation won't mean anything. The best approach for this would have to be some depth estimation from monocular images using deep learning.

[image]